# Is it possible to make a drop-down menu in the apiary markdown to select a host route?

Tags: documentation, api-doc, apiary.io

I'm putting together the documentation for an API for my system, so there are two APIs that do similar things and I would like to know so that I don't need to do more documentation for the other API, I would like to know if it is possible to manipulate the host from the apiary, placing a drop-down menu or something like that, that makes the user select the route he wants to use!

FORMAT: 1A 
HOST: https://api.example.net/api 
HOST: https://example.net/api